# Golang send messages to IBM MQ Error MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN

Tags: go, ibm-mq, esb

I'm now working with Golang to connect IBM Websphere MQ-ESB and libraries which I use to communicate with MQ-ESB are

```
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20
```

Generally, it can send the messages to MQ-ESB , but when something wrong happen the error MQ Connection Broken. This cause my app could not any longer send the messages to the MQ-ESB. Restarting service is the way to solve this issue (but it is not the way solve). Anyone has ideas?
Thanks

This is code create mq connection

```
func NewIBMMQConnection(mqConnConfig *mqjms.ConnectionFactoryImpl) jms20subset.JMSContext {
if !viper.GetBool("mq.openconnection") {
    return &mqjms.ContextImpl{}
}

logx.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
    "queue manager": viper.GetString("mq.qManager"),
    "host":          viper.GetString("mq.host"),
    "port":          viper.GetInt("mq.port"),
    "channel":       viper.GetString("mq.qChannel"),
}).Infof("[CONFIG] [MDM IBMMQ]")

conn, exception := mqConnConfig.CreateContext()
if exception != nil {
    if exception.GetLinkedError() != nil {
        logx.Fatalf("new mdm mq error: %s", exception.GetLinkedError())
    }
}
return conn
}

func NewIBMMQConfig() *mqjms.ConnectionFactoryImpl {
    return &mqjms.ConnectionFactoryImpl{
        QMName:      viper.GetString("mq.qManager"),
        Hostname:    viper.GetString("mq.host"),
        PortNumber:  viper.GetInt("mq.port"),
        ChannelName: viper.GetString("mq.qChannel"),
        UserName:    viper.GetString("mq.login"),
        Password:    viper.GetString("mq.pass"),
    }
}
```

This is the code in `main.go` that instantiate the connection

```
func main() {
    db := newGormDB()
    defer closeDB(db)

    mq := ibmmq.NewIBMMQConnection(ibmmq.NewIBMMQConfig())
    defer mq.Close()
    ibmmq := ibmmq.New(mq)

    ...

    ... 

    go startServer()

    shutdown()
}
```

This is code produce message

```
func (i *IBMMQ) ProduceMSGToMQ(ctx context.Context, msg string) error {
logx.WithContext(ctx).Infof("Producing Message queueName: message: %s", msg)
err := i.producer.SendString(i.queueCDDEMoeny, msg)

if err != nil {
    logx.WithSeverityError(ctx).Errorf("Send msg to mq error: %s", err.GetErrorCode()+"-"+err.GetReason()+"-"+err.GetLinkedError().Error())
    return errors.New("Send msg to mq error: " + err.GetErrorCode() + "-" + err.GetReason() + "-" + err.GetLinkedError().Error())
}
return nil
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code, specifically what your code does when it receives the MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN error.

Comment: Sure @MoragHughson.                                                                         

`func (i *IBMMQ) ProduceMSGToMQ(ctx context.Context, msg string) error {
 logx.WithContext(ctx).Infof("Producing Message queueName: message: %s", msg)
 err := i.producer.SendString(i.queueCDDEMoeny, msg)

 if err != nil {
  logx.WithSeverityError(ctx).Errorf("Send msg to mq error: %s", err.GetErrorCode()+"-"+err.GetReason())
  return errors.New("Send msg to mq error: " + err.GetErrorCode() + "-" + err.GetReason())
 }

 return nil
}`

Comment: That's rather hard to read. Could you edit your question and put it in there instead please?

Comment: Also, I don't see any code to connect to the queue manager there?

Comment: @MoragHughson Ok, I've already update the snippet that create connection and config :)

Comment: So when you get the error, you need to re-call the func that creates the connection.

Comment: @MoragHughson Could you provide some code snippet when error occurs and handler to create the connection or resume the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Go language expert, only an IBM MQ expert, but here goes (no pun intended!).

I don't see where you call your `ProduceMSGToMQ` function, but I imagine something like this:-

```
error := ibmmq.ProduceMSGToMQ(...)
if error != nil && (error.GetReason() == "MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN") {
    mq := ibmmq.NewIBMMQConnection(ibmmq.NewIBMMQConfig())
}
```

Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

We also had to restart service to restore connection on MQ client.
But the problem was resolved after setting the option to reconnect.

```
mqcno := ibmmq.NewMQCNO()
...
...
mqcno.Options = ibmmq.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING
mqcno.Options |= ibmmq.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR
```